# PyQt layout wrapper with indents

Tags: python, qt

As I'm sure a lot of you are aware, the layout files generated for Qt look quite horrible. Maya had a wrapper that let you indent each widget when building manually, so I decided to have a try with context managers.

I'm looking for a bit of feedback before I get much further. To start with I tried to keep a different type of naming convention for each style of widget (eg. is it a context manager, is it a layout or widget, etc), but it's got a bit more complicated keeping it consistent especially when combining multiple functions into one, so I'm not sure how well that part is going.

To show how it currently works, here's a test window with the code:

[image]

```
def setup_layout(parent):
    QtCustom.Parent.set(parent)

    with QtCustom.LayoutResizableV():
        with QtCustom.LayoutBoxH() as program_layout:
            program_layout.setContentsMargins(left=0)
            program_layout.setSpacing(6)

            QtCustom.QLabel('Image goes here')
            with QtCustom.WidgetTabGroup() as tab_group:
                tab_group.setFixedWidth(278)
                with QtCustom.TabScrollLayout('Render Options'):

                    with QtCustom.WidgetGroupBox('Profile Selection'), QtCustom.LayoutBoxV():
                        dropdown = QtCustom.QComboBox()
                        dropdown.addItems(['<current>', 'Default', 'Overwatch', 'Path of Exile'])

                    with QtCustom.WidgetGroupBox('Image Options'), QtCustom.LayoutBoxV():
                        QtCustom.QComboBox().addItems(['Tracks', 'Clicks', 'Acceleration', 'Keyboard'])
                        dropdown = QtCustom.QComboBox()
                        dropdown.addItems(['Time', 'Count'])
                        dropdown.setVisible(False)

                    with QtCustom.WidgetGroupBox('Colour Options'), QtCustom.LayoutBoxV():
                        with QtCustom.LayoutBoxH():
                            QtCustom.QLineEdit('Demon')
                            dropdown = QtCustom.QComboBox()
                            dropdown.addItems(['Presets', 'Citrus', 'Demon', 'Sunburst'])

                    with QtCustom.WidgetGroupBox('Saving'), QtCustom.LayoutBoxV():
                        QtCustom.QCheckBox('Only show current session')
                        with QtCustom.LayoutBoxH():
                            QtCustom.QPushButton('Save Image')
                            QtCustom.QStretch()
                            QtCustom.QPushButton('Export Data')

                    with QtCustom.WidgetGroupBox('Show/Hide Mouse Buttons'), QtCustom.LayoutBoxV():
                        checkbox = QtCustom.QCheckBox('Left Mouse Button')
                        checkbox.setChecked(True)
                        checkbox = QtCustom.QCheckBox('Middle Mouse Button')
                        checkbox.setChecked(True)
                        checkbox = QtCustom.QCheckBox('Right Mouse Button')
                        checkbox.setChecked(True)

                    QtCustom.QStretch()

                with QtCustom.TabScrollLayout('Advanced'):
                    QtCustom.QStretch()

        list_widget = QtCustom.QListWidget()
        list_widget.addItems(['test'])
```

As a brief rundown, `QtBase` is at the top, then `QtLayout` and `QtWidget` inherit from that, and everything else inherits from one of those. It keeps track of the current parent with `__enter__` and `__exit__`, which is how nothing needs to be passed into the classes (but it will correctly remember the parent of each class if you ask it later).

For the record I'm more interested in feedback based on the above code and how it looks/feels, but I'm all ears if anyone happens to have any good tips on how to improve the stuff below.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore

_DATA = {
    'parent': None,
    'family': {},
}

class Parent(object):
    """Automatically handle the parent tree when creating the layouts.
    When building a GUI, "Parent.set(parent_window)" must be called first.
    """

    @staticmethod
    def set(parent, grandparent=None):
        """Set the current parent.
        Optionally provide the next parent so it can be queried later.
        """
        _DATA['parent'] = parent
        if grandparent is not None:
            Parent.update(parent, grandparent)

    @staticmethod
    def get(child=None):
        """Get the current parent or parent of the given child."""
        if child:
            return _DATA['family'][child]
        return _DATA['parent']

    @staticmethod
    def update(child, parent):
        _DATA['family'][child] = parent


class QtBase(QtCore.QObject):
    """Base wapper class.
    Contains methods used by both the layout and widgets.
    """
    def __init__(self, qt_object, *args, **kwargs):
        Parent.set(self, Parent.get())
        parent = self.parent()

        try:
            QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        except KeyError:
            raise RuntimeError('the parent must first be set with Parent.set(parent)')

        if isinstance(parent, QtBase):
            parent._children.append(self)

        #Get information on the widget
        self._qt_data = {
            'object': qt_object,
            'created': not callable(qt_object),
            'type': qt_object if callable(qt_object) else qt_object.__class__,
            'args': args,
            'kwargs': kwargs
        }
        self._children = []
        self._children_data = {}

    def __enter__(self, inherit_funcs=[]):
        """Create the widget and inherit functions."""
        #Create the widget
        if self._qt_data['created']:
            self.QObject = self._qt_data['object']
        else:
            self.QObject = self._qt_data['object'](*self._qt_data['args'], **self._qt_data['kwargs'])

        #Inherit main funtions
        inherit_funcs += [
            'getContentsMargins',
            'addLayout',
            'addWidget',
            'setLayout',
            'setStyleSheet',
            'setObjectName',
            'setSizePolicy',
            'setToolTip',
        ]
        for func_name in inherit_funcs:
            if not hasattr(self, func_name):
                try:
                    func = getattr(self.QObject, func_name)
                    setattr(self, func_name, func)
                except AttributeError:
                    pass

        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        """Set the current parent one generation upwards."""
        parent = self.parent()
        Parent.set(parent)
        return parent

    def parent(self):
        return Parent.get(self)

    def setParent(self, parent):
        """Set a new parent.
        I've forgotten why the commented out bit is needed,
        but leaving it here just in case
        """
        #old_parent = self.parent()
        Parent.update(self, parent)
        #if parent.parent() == old_parent:
        #    Parent.set(parent)

    def setContentsMargins(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Set the contents margins.
        Supports a single number or 4 numbers, with optional overrides of
        "top", "left", "right" and "bottom".
        """
        margins = [None, None, None, None]
        #Set the base number first
        if args:
            num_args = len(args)
            if num_args == 1:
                margins = [args[0], args[0], args[0], args[0]]
            elif num_args == 4:
                margins = args
            else:
                raise TypeError('expect 1 or 4 arguments, got {}'.format(num_args))

        #Handle overrides
        if kwargs:
            for i, keyword in enumerate(['left', 'top', 'right', 'bottom']):
                if kwargs.get(keyword) is not None:
                    margins[i] = kwargs[keyword]

        #Set any remaining values
        if sum([i is not None for i in margins]) != 4:
            margins = [i if i is not None else j for i, j in zip(margins, self.getContentsMargins())]
        self.QObject.setContentsMargins(*margins)


class QtLayout(QtBase):
    """Wrapper for layout widgets."""
    def __init__(self, widget, *args, **kwargs):
        QtBase.__init__(self, widget, *args, **kwargs)
        self._converted = False

    def __enter__(self, inherit_funcs=[]):
        inherit_funcs += [
            'getContentsMargins',
            'setSpacing',
            'addStretch',
        ]
        QtBase.__enter__(self, inherit_funcs)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        """Add layout to parent layout.
        Some layouts can only take widgets,
        so we have to convert the class for some of them.
        """
        parent = QtBase.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

        #Convert QMainWindow to widget so layouts can be added
        if isinstance(parent, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
            parent.setCentralWidget(self._convert_to_widget())

        #Handle QtLayout classes
        elif isinstance(parent, QtLayout):
            parent.addLayout(self.QObject)

        #Handle QtWidget classes
        elif isinstance(parent, QtWidget):
            if isinstance(parent, (WidgetTab, WidgetGroupBox)):
                parent.setLayout(self.QObject)
            elif isinstance(parent, WidgetScrollArea):
                parent.setWidget(self._convert_to_widget())
            else:
                parent.addWidget(self._convert_to_widget())

        #Handle any other base types
        else:
            parent.setLayout(self.QObject)

    def _convert_to_widget(self):
        """Convert the current layout to a widget."""
        if self._converted:
            return self.parent()

        #Get the parent to pass into the widget
        parent = self.parent()
        if isinstance(parent, QtBase):
            parent = parent.QObject

        #Wrap the current layout in a widget
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent)
        widget.setLayout(self.QObject)
        Parent.update(widget, parent)
        self.setParent(widget)
        self._converted = True
        return widget


class QtWidget(QtBase):
    """Wrapper for widgets."""
    def __init__(self, widget, *args, **kwargs):
        QtBase.__init__(self, widget, *args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self, inherit_funcs=[]):
        inherit_funcs += [
            'setVisible',
            'setEnabled'
            'setReadOnly',
            'setAlignment',
            'setMinimumWidth',
            'setMaximumWidth',
            'setMinimumHeight',
            'setMaximumHeight',
            'setFixedWidth',
            'setFixedHeight',
        ]
        QtBase.__enter__(self, inherit_funcs)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        """Add widget to parent layout."""
        parent = QtBase.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

        #Set widget if parent is a QMainWindow
        if isinstance(parent, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
            parent.setCentralWidget(self.QObject)

        else:
            parent.addWidget(self.QObject)


class LayoutResizable(QtWidget):
    """Context manager for QSplitter."""
    def __init__(self, orientation, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidget.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QSplitter, orientation, *args, **kwargs)


class LayoutResizableH(LayoutResizable):
    """Context manager for QSplitter set to horizontal."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        LayoutResizable.__init__(self, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, *args, **kwargs)


class LayoutResizableV(LayoutResizable):
    """Context manager for QSplitter set to vertical."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        LayoutResizable.__init__(self, QtCore.Qt.Vertical, *args, **kwargs)


class LayoutBoxH(QtLayout):
    """Context manager for QHBoxLayout."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtLayout.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout, *args, **kwargs)


class LayoutBoxV(QtLayout):
    """Context manager for QVBoxLayout."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtLayout.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout, *args, **kwargs)


class WidgetLabel(QtWidget):
    """Context manager for QLabel."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidget.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QLabel, *args, **kwargs)


def QLabel(*args, **kwargs):
    """Wrapper for QLabel."""
    with WidgetLabel(*args, **kwargs) as widget:
        return widget


class WidgetPushButton(QtWidget):
    """Context manager for QPushButton."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidget.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QPushButton, *args, **kwargs)


def QPushButton(*args, **kwargs):
    """Wrapper for QPushButton."""
    with WidgetPushButton(*args, **kwargs) as widget:
        return widget


class WidgetLineEdit(QtWidget):
    """Context manager for QLineEdit."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidget.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QLineEdit, *args, **kwargs)


def QLineEdit(*args, **kwargs):
    """Wrapper for QLineEdit."""
    with WidgetLineEdit(*args, **kwargs) as widget:
        return widget


class WidgetCheckBox(QtWidget):
    """Context manager for QtWidgets.QCheckBox."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidget.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QCheckBox, *args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        return QtWidget.__enter__(self, ['checkState', 'setChecked', 'isChecked'])


def QCheckBox(*args, **kwargs):
    """Wrapper for QtWidgets.QCheckBox."""
    with WidgetCheckBox(*args, **kwargs) as widget:
        return widget


class WidgetComboBox(QtWidget):
    """Context manager for QComboBox."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidget.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QComboBox, *args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        return QtWidget.__enter__(self, ['addItem', 'addItems'])


def QComboBox(*args, **kwargs):
    """Wrapper for QComboBox."""
    with WidgetComboBox(*args, **kwargs) as widget:
        return widget


class WidgetListWidget(QtWidget):
    """Context manager for QListWidget."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidget.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QListWidget, *args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        return QtWidget.__enter__(self, ['addItem', 'addItems'])


def QListWidget(*args, **kwargs):
    """Wrapper for QListWidget."""
    with WidgetListWidget(*args, **kwargs) as widget:
        return widget


def QStretch():
    """Wrapper for addStretch."""
    parent = Parent.get()
    parent.addStretch()


class WidgetTabGroup(QtWidget):
    """Context manager for QTabWidget."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidget.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QTabWidget, *args, **kwargs)
        self._num_tabs = 0

    def __enter__(self):
        return QtWidget.__enter__(self, ['addTab'])


class WidgetTab(QtWidget):
    """Context manager for a tab (QWidget)."""
    def __init__(self, name='', *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidget.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QWidget, *args, **kwargs)
        if not isinstance(self.parent(), WidgetTabGroup):
            raise TypeError('incorrect parent type, expected "WidgetTabGroup", got "{}"'.format(self.parent().__class__.__name__))
        self._name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        QtWidget.__enter__(self, ['setLayout'])
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        parent = QtBase.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
        parent.addTab(self.QObject, self._name)


@contextmanager
def TabScrollLayout(*args, **kwargs):
    """Context manager for a new tab containing a scroll area."""
    with WidgetTab(*args, **kwargs) as tab_widget:
        tab_widget.setContentsMargins(0)
        with LayoutBoxV() as tab_layout:
            with WidgetScrollArea() as scroll_widget:
                with LayoutBoxV() as scroll_layout:
                    yield (tab_layout, scroll_widget, scroll_layout)


class WidgetScrollArea(QtWidget):
    """Context manager for QScrollArea."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidget.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QScrollArea, *args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        QtWidget.__enter__(self, ['setWidget', 'setWidgetResizable'])
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        return self


class WidgetGroupBox(QtWidget):
    """Context manager for QGroupBox."""
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        QtWidget.__init__(self, QtWidgets.QGroupBox, name)
        if not isinstance(self.parent(), QtBase):
            raise TypeError('incorrect parent type, expected "QtBase", got "{}"'.format(self.parent().__class__.__name__))
```